# Power supply has 2-pin, 6-pin and 8-pin connectors, board wants 4-pin. Which one is right?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, graphics-card

I bought a new power supply which has additional power connectors. There is 6-pin connector (3x2) which is labeled "pcie". There is another 2-pin connector which can be attached to the 6-pin and there is a 8-pin (4x2) which is unlabled and can be split into two 2x2. My old power supply only had a 2x2 and my board needs a 2x2.

I did not connect any of these conenctors which results in my graphics card staying dark. The card does not have a 3x2 socket. What are these connectors for? Am I supposed to split the 4x2?

Board: AS-Rock ALiveDual-ESATA-2
Power Supply: Energon EPS-650W
Graphics Card: MSI nVidia GeForce 8600

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You split the 4x2 connector and use that for the 4-pin motherboard 12v socket. Some new motherboards have a 4x2 connector or 2 2x2 connectors.

Looking around it seems that your gfx-card does not need the pcie 6pin connector. Many of the "higher end" cards need this to get enough power. I suspect that the black screen you're seeing is because you haven't connected the 12v motherboard connector.

Comment: I was very brave. I connected one of the 2x2 connectors the the mother board and turned the machine on (holding breath and having the fire extinguisher ready). http://instantrimshot.com/ ;-)

Comment: @EricSchaefer That pretty much describes every time I do a custom build and get ready to rock that PSU switch.

Answer (score 2):

They're called "pins", not "poles". (In electrical engineering and design, poles are something else entirely.)

The 8-pin PCIe plug might split into two 4-pin ATX12V connectors (square), but that would be very unusual (probably the pinout forbids it, I'm too lazy to check). What you probably need, depending on the card, is either a standard 4-pin molex power connector (same as for a hard drive) or a 4-pin floppy power connector.

Comment: Well, in German it is called "4-polig" which translates to 4-pole according to my dictionary. Will change the question though...

I need a connector for the motherboard, not the gfx-card. It should look like the 3 connectors, but only with 2x2 pins. The socket on the board does not look like HD or FD power connectors.